# Few basics in cocos2d-x v3 Windows

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have some basic questions about some Problems in cocos2d-x v3.

1.) when I create sprites like that:

```
cocos2d::Sprite *sprite1 = cocos2d::Sprite::create("test.png");
auto sprite2 = cocos2d::Sprite::create("test.png");
```

How I have to to erease them proplery? Should I use autorelease (it crashes when I use it after create it)? Can I for both variants just use:

```
sprite1->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
sprite2->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
```

2.) When I want an Animation have active in my HelloWorldScene, so that i can use it when i want, how can I do it? I tried something like that:

```
void HelloWorld::runAnimationWalk() {
    auto spritebatch = cocos2d::SpriteBatchNode::create("robo.png");
    auto cache = cocos2d::SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
    cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("robo.plist");
    //spritebatch->addChild(worker);
    Vector<SpriteFrame *> animFrames(5);
    char str[100] = {0};

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
    {
        sprintf(str, "robot%i.png", i);
        cocos2d::SpriteFrame* frame = cache->getSpriteFrameByName( str );
        animFrames.pushBack(frame);
    }

    auto animWalk = cocos2d::Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, 0.1f);   

    vector<Worker>::iterator it = workerVector.begin();
    for(int k = 0; k<workerVector.size();k++) {
        if(it->getType() == 1) 
            it->getWorker()->runAction(RepeatForever::create(Animate::create(animWalk)));
        it++;
    }
}
```

That works, but i have to call the function always after I want to change the animation. I tried to save the spritebatch, cache etc... global, but the animation dissaperars after a few time.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1)** Yes. This is a full scenario:

```
//Create
Sprite *sprite1 = cocos2d::Sprite::create("test.png");
this->addChild(sprite1);

// Deleter Later
sprite1->removeFromParent();
```

**Answer 2)** You can create an animation ( `Animation*` ) and run it on any sprite.
some note:

1. If you want the animation play again and again, you can make a infinite version of your animation with `RepeatForever::create(YourAnimation)`.
2. If you want to create the animation but use(display) it later. you can create your `Animation*` and `retain()` it until you run it on some target(sprite). (don't forget ro `release` it when running on target)